# Fixing An Undefined variable error in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling, notice

I've built a little blog website but I keep getting errors in the log file after every visit.  The error reads, `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: post_id in /***/***/***/post.php on line 33`

I've found that it's a result of having multiple outputs (`$x .= "display"`) and was told that putting in another one to define it should work, but it doesn't.  What I mean is:

```
<?php
$display_posts = "0";
?>
<?php
$posts_sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 10";
$posts_res = mysqli_query($con, $posts_sql);
while($post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($posts_res)){
    $post_id = $post["id"];
    etc
    etc

    $display_posts .= "

        <div class=\"block\"></div>

    ";
}
?>
```

Now in my page I get the output displayed but a `0` is shown above it.  How do I sort out the original `PHP Notice`?

Comment: Where do you define $artic_title ?

Comment: Are you sure that `artic_title` should not be `article_title`?

Comment: @Cyclone Yeah probably.  Let's use `post_id` instead!!!